# Php send JSON response but $.getJSON didnt receive it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a problem with the JSON response I'm returning from my PHP code.

THe PHP on the backend

```
case 'deleteMySale':
    $id = $_GET['product_id'];
    $dataNoSer = "you want to delete sale where id= " . $id . "?";
    $data =  json_encode($dataNoSer, true);
    echo $data;
    break;
```

The JavaScript on the front-end that is calling the PHP

```js
$('.deleteProduct').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/myProject/deleteMySale?product_id=20", function (data) {
        console.log("success");
    })
            .done(function () {
                console.log("second success");
            })
            .fail(function () {
                console.log("error");
            })
            .always(function () {
                console.log("complete");
            });
})
```

Response

```
error
complete
```

The PHP function is called when I click the button, but I consistently get an error in the console.

Why does jQuery not receive the JSON data?
I've read similar problems and their solutions, but I canott see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: there is a problem with your PHP

Comment: capture the error object: `.fail(function(err) { console.log(err); }` and see WHY it failed. a fixed "error" message is essentially useless for debugging.

Comment: what do you get if you open `http://localhost/myProject/deleteMySale?product_id=20` directly in a browser?

Comment: @Alex i get {"question":"you want to delete sale where id= 20?"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a malformed JSON response. The issue is that you've passed a flat string to the encode function. The encode function does not encode strings, it encodes arrays and objects. Let's make it an array so we can get a real response.

$dataNoSer = array("question" => "you want to delete sale where id= " . $id . "?");

Also, if necessary, modify the headers before sending the response so that you're sure it's an `application/json` content-type on the response.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Access it like so.

```
console.log(data.question);
```

Comment: i modify the dataNoSer as you wrote. 
In Javascript i still get "Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined" when i write console.log in .fail or .always

Comment: When i set header('Content-Type: application/json'); the site look like not interpreted html code

Comment: Your `header` should only appear before the `echo $data`; in your conditional statement, not at the top of the file. you only want to affect what you're returning. Furthermore, if you're going to use `function(data){}` then you're going to need to `console.log(data)` within there. otherwise, if you are going to use `.always()` then you need to add `data` as an argument to that callback. `.always(data)` for instance.

Comment: Thank You for information. But still the function don't work properly.the Now i get other interesting error: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\myProject\vendor\smarty\smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_template.php:306)